# How to create dictionary for students and multiple courses grades?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, generics

I am learning C# dictionary and I am confused how to do this

I have a Dictionary of students names. and I would like to assign another dictionary to that.

my input similar to this

Student1:
 Math,9
 Science,5
 English,2

Student2:
 Math,9
 Science,10
 English,7

I tried to create a class called Info and here is my code

```
    public class Info
    {
        public string course { get; set; }
        public int grade { get; set; }

        public Info(string c, int g)
        {
            course = c;
            grade = g;
        }

        internal IDictionary<string, Info> infoDic { get; private set; }

        public void Set(string Sname, string course, int grade)
        {
            Student s = new Student(Sname);
            var infor = new Info(course, grade);
            infoDic = new Dictionary<string, Info>();
            infoDic.Add(s.Name, infor);

            //return infoDic;
        } 

        public Dictionary<string, Info> retrieve (string name)
        {
            Student s = new Student(name);
            return infoDic;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is another attempt:

I tried to make the class Info , and in the main I create the Dictionary and give the values, but the problem is I have lets say 3 courses and 10 students, and sometimes I need to retrieve only the math grades for all students.

How to improve the code to differentiate between the courses? Or how to make the course name as another key?

```
public class Info
    {
        public string course { get; set; }
        public int grade { get; set; }

        public Info(string c, int g)
        {
            course = c;
            grade = g;
        }

    }


    class Test
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Dictionary<string, Info> information = new Dictionary<string, Info>();
            Info i1 = new Info("math", 9);
            information.Add("Student1", i1);
            Info i2 = new Info("science", 11);
            information.Add("Student1", i2);
            Info i3 = new Info("math", 13);
            information.Add("student2", i3);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Info> eee in information)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", eee.Key, eee.Value.type, eee.Value.count);
            }

        }
    }
```

I need two methods one to set the values that user enters and the other to retrieve a certain course values when the user requires them

Is there Any suggestions?

Comment: I would start off by taking a step back and renaming things. What is "info"? It's hard to tell just from the name. It's hard to tell from the names of the constructor parameters (`c` and `g`). It sounds like it's a single student's result in a single course. It knows about the course and the grade, but that's all. How about `CourseResult` or something similar as a name then? Then rename your dictionary variable from `information` (everything's information, after all) to something like `studentResults`: Dictionary<string, CourseResult> studentResults = ...;` gives a *lot* more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the problem into separate concerns.

Use the `Student` and `Info` classes just to store data. Importantly, every Student holds a collection of his courses.

```
public class Student {

    public Student(string name) {
        Name = name;
        Infos = new List<Info>();
    }

    public string Name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Info> Infos {get; set;}
}

public class Info {
    public Info(string course, int grade) {
        Course = course;
        Grade = grade;
    }

    public string Course { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Data access is handled by a different class `StudentRepository`.
The central dictionary is of type `IDictionary<string, Student>` with the Student name as key and hidden inside the repository.

```
using System.Linq;

public class StudentRepository {
    public StudentRepository() {
       _studentsByName = new Dictionary<string, Student>();
    }

    // keep data store private so we can change the implementation
    private IDictionary<string, Student> _studentsByName {get; set;}

    public void Add(Student student) {
        if (_studentsByName.ContainsKey(student.Name)) {
           throw new ArgumentException($"Student '{student.Name}' already stored.");
        }
        _studentsByName.Add(student.Name, student);
    }

    public Student Get(string studentName) {
        if (_studentsByName.ContainsKey(studentName)) {
           return _studentsByName[studentName];
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("No student '" + studentName + "' stored.");
    }

    // Find Grade for certain student and course
    public int GetGrade(string studentName, string course) {
        if (_studentsByName.ContainsKey(studentName)) {
            var student = _studentsByName[studentName];
            var courseInfo = student.Infos.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Course == course);
            if (courseInfo != null) {
                return courseInfo.Grade;
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"Student '{studentName}' did not take the course '{course}'.");
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new ArgumentException($"No student '{studentName}' found.");
        }
    }

    // Get dictionary of all students that took a certain course. Key: student name
    public IDictionary<string, Info> GetCoursesByStudentName(string course) {

        // Use LINQ to retrieve the infos you need. 
        // Here I create a new dictionary with Student name as Key and 
        // the first matching course info found as value.
        // (Students that did not take this course are not in this dictionary):
        return _studentsByName 
            .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.Infos.Any(i => i.Course == course))
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, 
                          kvp => kvp.Value.Infos.First(i => i.Course == course));
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
const string MathCourseName = "Math";

var Student1 = new Student("Alice");
Student1.Infos.Add(new Info(MathCourseName, 4));

var Student2 = new Student("Bob");
Student2.Infos.Add(new Info(MathCourseName, 2));

var Student3 = new Student("Cesar");
Student3.Infos.Add(new Info("English", 3));

var repository = new StudentRepository();

repository.Add(Student1);
repository.Add(Student2);
repository.Add(Student3);

foreach(var kvp in repository.GetCoursesByStudentName(MathCourseName)) {
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value.Course + " - " + kvp.Value.Grade); 
}

var bobsMathGrade = repository.GetGrade("Bob", MathCourseName);
Console.WriteLine("Bobs math grade: " + bobsMathGrade);
```

[C# Fiddle for this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/am9OAl)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your explanation is helpful. I would like to ask what is the usage of "FirstOrDefault" ? @GeorgPatscheider

Comment: [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the first element in the collection that matches the criteria. If no matching element can be found, the default value (`null` for reference types) will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

What i understood from your statement, you need two methods: One for setting user values and other for getting user's course value, i've slightly modified your code in order to fulfill you requirement, you can do like this:

```
public class Info
    {
        public string course { get; set; }
        public int grade { get; set; }

        public Info(string c, int g)
        {
            course = c;
            grade = g;
        }

    }

    public class Student
    {
        public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>> student { get; set; }
        public Student()
        {
            student = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public void SetValue(string studentName, Info info)
        {

            if (!student.ContainsKey(studentName))
            {
                Dictionary<string, int> stud_info = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                stud_info.Add(info.course, info.grade);
                student.Add(studentName, stud_info);
            }
            else
            {
                student[studentName].Add(info.course, info.grade);
            }
        }


        public Dictionary<string,int> GetValue(string studentName, string course)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> info = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            if (student.ContainsKey(studentName))
            {
                if (student[studentName].ContainsKey(course))
                {
                    int grade = 0;
                    if(student[studentName].TryGetValue(course, out grade))
                    {
                        info.Add(course, grade);
                        return info;
                    }
                }
            }
            return info;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            Info i1 = new Info("math", 9);
            student.SetValue("Student1", i1);
            Info i2 = new Info("science", 11);
            student.SetValue("Student1",i2);
            Info i3 = new Info("math", 13);
            student.SetValue("Student2", i3);

            Dictionary<string, int> value = student.GetValue("Student2", "math");
            //Grade of math for student2
            Console.WriteLine("Grade: {0}", value["math"]);
        }


    }
```